# Dot notation in Mongo with PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb

This [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#insert-documents) shows a simple insert:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->example->users;

$insertOneResult = $collection->insertOne([
    'username' => 'admin',
    'email' => 'admin@example.com',
    'name' => 'Admin User',
]);

printf("Inserted %d document(s)\n", $insertOneResult->getInsertedCount());

var_dump($insertOneResult->getInsertedId());
```

... but using the latest PHP driver, I get an error if I have a `.` in the collection name (`collection.attribute`), for example:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->collection.attribute->users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->{'collection.attribute'}->users;
```